# Typo3 indexed search crawler error while indexing

Tags: web-crawler, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I have installed indexed_search and crawler (development version compatible with typo3 6.2) in a TYPO3 6.2.9 system.

Being in "WEB > Info > Site Crawler > Crawler Log" I can start the indexing of a page. But when I click the read button to start indexing of pages, I get an error message: "Error: 501 //'; message_html += ''; message_html..."

Changing to "ADMIN TOOLS > Indexing, I can see that no pages were indexed.

Does anybody know how can I solve this problem?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Best regards

Arun Chandran

Comment: try https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/crawler

Comment: I've tried this, but still display the same error message.

Comment: I've figured out the problem. The problem happened due to server side firewall blocking.